# Why EclipseLink 's auto commit doesn't work with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

Using the following code:

```
EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);
PhysicalCard card = new PhysicalCard();
card.setIdentifier("012345ABCDEF");
card.setStatus(CardStatusEnum.Assigned);

manager.persist(card);
manager.close();
```

when code runs to this line, the "card" record does not appear in the database. However, if using the FlushModeType.COMMIT, and using transaction like this:

```
EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

manager.getTransaction().begin();
PhysicalCard card = new PhysicalCard();
card.setIdentifier("012345ABCDEF");
card.setStatus(CardStatusEnum.Assigned);

manager.persist(card);
manager.getTransaction().commit();

manager.close();
```

it works fine. From the eclipselink's log i can see the previous code doesn't issue an INSERT statement while the second code does.

Do I miss something here? I'm using EclipseLink 2.3 and mysql connection/J 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using EclipseLink in a Java SE application, or in a Java EE application but with an application managed EntityManager instead of a container managed EntityManager.

In both scenarios, all updates made to the persistence context are flushed only when the transaction associated with the EntityManager commits (using [`EntityTransaction.commit`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#commit%28%29)), or when the EntityManager's persistence context is flushed (using [`EntityManager.flush`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29)). This is the reason why the second code snippet issues the INSERT as it invokes the `EntityTransaction`'s `begin` and `commit` methods, while the first doesn't; an invocation of `em.persist` does not issue an `INSERT`.

As far as `FlushModeType` values are concerned, [the API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html) states the following:

> **COMMIT**
>
> public static final FlushModeType COMMIT
>
> Flushing to occur at transaction commit. The provider may flush at
>   other times, but is not required to.
>
> ---
>
> **AUTO**
>
> public static final FlushModeType AUTO
>
> (Default) Flushing to occur at query execution.

Since, queries haven't been executed in the first case case, no flushing i.e. no `INSERT` statements corresponding to the persistence of the `PhysicalCard` entity will be issued. It is the explicit commit of the `EntityTransaction` in the second, that is resulting in the `INSERT` statement being issued.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but still something i don't quite understand. When I use the default FlushModelType.Auto, and issues a flush() after the persist(), an Exception occurs when flush, complaining No transaction is currently active.

Comment: I think you've confused `FlushModeType` with something else. It is meant to define the flushing behavior of the JPA provider when a query has to be executed, so that the results of the query are consistent with any changes made to the persistence context.

Comment: As far as the exception thrown is concerned, well I'm not surprised. `EntityManager.persist` will do nothing if there is no transaction and `EntityManager.flush` requires a transaction to flush changes in the persistence context. If you do not start a transaction using `EntityManager.getTransaction.begin()`, then there is no transaction associated with the persistence context, which results in the error on `EntityManager.flush`.

Comment: If I have to state anything further, it would be that transactions are usually associated with container managed EntityManager instances in a Java EE container. In a Java SE application, you have to start a transaction. Also, `EntityManager.persist` is only useful for marking a entity as a managed entity that is to be persisted later. It is `EntityManager.flush` or `EntityTransaction.commit` that actually issues the `INSERT` statement to the database (see my answer).